# how to maintain group ID for bulk create in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Below generate primary key auto-incremented but is there any way to assign or generate group id to those record which creates in one particular bulk using sequelize with MySQL.
or there is any way in mysql

here is my code

```
Model.bulkCreate(data,{individualHooks: true})

.then(function(result) {

console.log(result)
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by group id?

Comment: Bulk insert is controlled by you isn't it, can you not have a column in your table that can take as per the number of batch you are processing? I guess I'm not wrong in understanding your question!

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer yeah exactly you are right bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this,

first, I add the field with name groupId and then get groupid on every insertion and append with request bod.got time now so posting now :) might help some one else

```
tasks.max('groupId').then(function (maxid) {
                        var newbody = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
                            body.groupId = maxid + 1;
                            newbody.push(body);
                        }
                        tasks.bulkCreate(newbody, {individualHooks: true}).then(function (taskvalues) {
                            res.status(200).json(taskvalues);
                        }).catch(function (err) {

                            res.status(500).json(err);

                        })
```